# Is it possible to do hot reloading when working with react and meteor?

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs

I'm working on an application where I use meteor and react.

One of my React components looks like this:

```
MyModal = React.createClass({
    openModal() {
        this.setState({active: true});
    },
    closeModal() {
        this.setState({active: false});
    },
    getInitialState() {
        return {
            active: this.props.isVisible
        }
    },
    render() {
        return (
            <div className={"modal "+(this.state.active ? 'active' : '')}>              
                <div className="content">
                    <span className="closeModal fa fa-times" onClick={this.closeModal}></span>

                    {this.props.children}
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
})
```

Now, whenever I change my components code, the whole page reloads and the state is reset. Is there a way to keep the current state of the component? As far as I know this is possible with react hot reloader, but is it also possible when using meteor?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Should be possible with certain flavors of flux (https://forums.meteor.com/t/flux-example-app-with-react-meteor/7416/18).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can integrate Webpack with your Meteor application using [this package.](https://github.com/thereactivestack/meteor-webpack)

There's also [this boilerplate](https://github.com/thereactivestack/kickstart-simple)  if you wanna start from scratch:

It's not trivial to start using webpack within your existing app, but it'll be well worth it for the following reasons:

- Hot-reload with React
- ES6 modules: this is the future!
- Code splitting: only load a part of the application in the client and load the rest when they need it.

Answer (score 0):

After a while of research we stumbled upon [this boilerplate](https://github.com/jedwards1211/meteor-webpack-react) and went with it. We did quiet a lot of customizations (especially to get testing to work with Meteor functions too) and now it works like a charm.

As the other answer already says "it's well worth the effort".